# Upgrading phpMyAdmin to 4.3.4

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, config

I was trying to upgrade phpMyAdmin to 4.3.4 (latest version)
And I was backup (my untouched) `config.inc.php` file and put it back
on phpMyAdmin directory.

Because I wasn't using password on root I was getting an (2) error message(s).

1.

```
 The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why.
      Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there
```

2.

```
Your configuration file contains settings (root with no password) that correspond to the default MySQL privileged account. Your MySQL server is running with this default, is open to intrusion, and you really should fix this security hole by setting a password for user 'root'.
```

So I was trying to correct them and start with the easiest one and put a password on my `config.inc.php` file... guess what a new error (ACCESS DENIED).

Error

```
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

If I completely remove `config.inc.php` file I'm getting a logon screen so I'm trying to use the default user : root pass: (no password) and it's not logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to change the password in the mysql server before you change it in phpmyadmin configuration. The other way round, you lock yourself out.

You need to connect to the server using command line tools like

```
mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password newpass
```

For example

```
mysqladmin -u root -p'abc' password '123456'
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got similar issues when I upgraded phpmyadmin on my xampp to 4.4.15.3 version.

[image: screenshot]

[image: Errors screenshot]

To fix this I copied following values from *config.sample.inc.php* and moved to *config.inc.php*

after /* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */ line

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
```

and restarted the mysql server.